# react.js prevent attribute from being written

Tags: javascript, reactjs

suppose I have a react.js component with this render method (using jsx):

```
render: function() {
  return (
    <a href={this.state.something?this.props.url:null}>Click</a>
  );
}
```

Regardless of the uselessness of this component, my question is this:

In case of `something` being false, react renders this as `<a href>Click</a>`, but I would rather have it render as `<a>Click</a>`.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use object spread here if it's supported!

```
var props = {href:this.props.url};
if(!this.state.something){
    props = {}
}
return <a {...props}>Click</a>
```

Comment: Ok, tried it. But it does not work either. During JSX transpilation, babeljs gives me a syntax error at the opening { in <a {...

Comment: You may need to upgrade your babel to the latest version to support Object rest/spread.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by the following code, basically adding the "href" to the url.

```
render: function() {
  return (
    <a {this.state.something?"href="+this.props.url:null}>Click</a>
  );
}
```

Comment: Ok, tried it. But it does not work. During JSX transpilation, babeljs gives me a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make sure the `href` doesn't appear then you could do like this and also avoid text in the ternary operator for a somewhat cleaner look

```
render = function() {
  props = this.state.something? {href: this.props.url} : {};
  el = react.createElement('a', props, 'Click');
  return el;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I would've just prefered a jsx solution :)